# Number pipe doesn't format value if you delete comma

Tags: angular, typescript

I have working example of my number pipe that I use in input fields:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/decimal-pipe-comma-separator-example-arg-h3gtrw?file=app%2Fshared%2Fnumber.pipe.ts

For e.g. when I enter 11111 and click outside the input it gets formatted to 11,111. However when I delete the comma and click outside the input again it doesn't get formatted with comma again. Why could this be? It seems to return correct value when I debug the code, but it shows unformatted number instead. It seems to be the case with original angular DecimalPipe too. How could I fix it?

I add pipe and html code below too:

```js
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'numberFormat'
})
export class NumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number | string, minFractionDigits: number = 0, maxFractionDigits: number = 2, locale: string = 'en'): string {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
      minimumFractionDigits: minFractionDigits,
      maximumFractionDigits: maxFractionDigits
    }).format(Number(value));
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" [ngModel]="userNum | numberFormat" (ngModelChange)="userNum=$event" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to make the pipe impure?

Comment: just added pure: false to pipe and it doesn't seem to help or I should add something else besides that?

Comment: Nope. I thought that that was the issue. My internet connection is bad. I'm having issues loading the stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number value does not change, the view is not updated. You can force change detection by setting an intermediate dummy value before setting the real one:

```html
<input type="text" 
  [ngModel]="userNum | numberFormat"
  (ngModelChange)="setUserNum($event)" 
  [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}">
```

```js
setUserNum(value) {
  this.userNum = undefined;                // Set temporary value
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();  // Force change detection
  this.userNum = value;                    // Set actual value (triggers change detection)
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/decimal-pipe-comma-separator-example-arg-d4wqvf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

---

If you want to use that technique on several fields, you can define a general `setValue` method, in which you access the property by its name:

```html
<input type="text" 
  [ngModel]="userNum | numberFormat"
  (ngModelChange)="setValue('userNum', $event)" 
  [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn:'blur'}">
```

```js
setValue(key, value) {
  this[key] = undefined;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  this[key] = value;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/decimal-pipe-comma-separator-example-arg-jkuvg7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: this looks cool, but if I had 10 inputs I would need 10 methods where I would set this.userNum = value , this.userNum1 = value , this.userNum2 = value, etc so it's not universal solution

Comment: I added to the answer a reusable version of the same technique.